# As a tourist, can I bring an expensive computer tower to Mexico from the United States?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, tourist-visas, mexico

I’m planning an extended stay in Cozumel this winter (180 days). I plan on working while I’m there and would like to bring my newish Mac Pro with me but I’m not sure if I’m allowed to  bring something like this into Mexico.

## Question

Using a standard tourist visa. Am I allowed to bring an expensive computer tower from the US to Mexico? What are the rules and considerations I need to take into account?

Comment: I’ve been to Cozumel many times and have a secure place to stay.

Comment: On a tourist visa?

Comment: @WeatherVane yes, I’m a standard tourist visa.

Comment: So how are you going to explain the expensive computer tower, which you be using to work?

Comment: @WeatherVane for working remotely while I’m on vacation.

Comment: Six months isn't a typical vacation.

Comment: I think Mexico is tolerant and has a digital nomad visa.

Comment: Setting aside the visa considerations (which you should probably explore, but that’s for another question), you can definitely bring the computer. The issue is that you risk having to pay taxes and duties on that, which can be complex and costly. In theory there is often a possibility to get those taxes and duties back when you re-export it, but again, complex. You may even face complication when you return with the US wanting to tax you as well. One option may be an ATA Carnet, but I’m not sure a 6-month holiday fits within the usage rules.

Comment: Would you be taking all the extras such as monitor, keyboard, etc.?  Or just the tower?  My memory of these is that they're relatively small, is that correct?

Comment: Are you asking whether you can take it on the plane?  Whether you're legally allowed to take it into Mexico?  Whether you'll have to pay to bring it in?  How "newish" is it?  I mean people bring laptops and other work equipment into other countries all the time

Comment: @WeatherVane Mexico allows people to work remotely (for non-Mexico companies) on regular tourist permits and visas.  (working for Mexican companies though is a strict NO without a work permit)

Comment: @jcaron To prevent US re-import taxes, you can fill out a [CBP Form 4457](https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2022/03/22/2022-06024/certificate-of-registration-cbp-forms-4455-and-4457) and have it validated at the border before departure, much less expensive than an ATA Carnet.

Comment: @jcaron I'm confused as to why a computer tower is supposed to be treated any different from a laptop, which hundreds of thousands of people carry across the border during their vacation with zero tax. A fully loaded M2 Mac Pro is $8k, for example.

Comment: @JonathanReez it is just going to be more difficult to convince customs that you travel back and forth with that, and that you’re intending to import definitively the computer rather than temporarily. In many countries they could actually tax anything you bring in beyond your duty free allowance, and it’s just because it would be a bit hindrance to tourism and business that they allow lots of stuff unchecked, hoping it will make its way back out. But try that with a brand new laptop in original packaging and see how things can change…

Comment: @jcaron but are you saying that if I report my 1-year old laptop to Mexican customs, they'll ask me to pay duty on it during my 1-month vacation in Cabo? I don't think OP was importing a brand new desktop in packaging.

Comment: @JonathanReez don’t know the specifics for Mexico, but my guess is that they probably won’t because they don’t want to spend time on that, though they could. That’s the whole reason behind ATA Carnets: make sure some diligent customs officer doesn’t try to tax something you are importing temporarily. They don’t have to trust you when you say you will take it back out in a few days/weeks. And even though they will probably believe it (or even think it before you even say anything) for stuff like the millions of laptops they see, as soon as it’s unusual and expensive…

Comment: @JonathanReez note that I’m not saying it _will_ happen, but it’s a clear possibility. Big Mac Pro nicely packaged, 6 months stay… and OP’s self-answer shows that it did happen.

Comment: @jcaron I guess my question is whether or not that's truly Mexico's policy or if OP just happened to meet clueless customs employees who didn't understand his intentions correctly. It just seems absurd that an $8k Mac pro would sail on through but a $3k desktop would not.

Comment: @jonathanreez see my take on this gray area is this old answer https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/174560/30703

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is Yes, but they will charge you import tax on the item. I learned this the hard-way, but fortunately they didn't charge me tax on the full price of the item, just what I stated it was worth.

I was told that a Digital Nomad Visa would allow me to avoid this import tax on work related items.

Comment: Obtaining an ATA Carnet is also an option.

Comment: @gparyani Interesting, I'll read up on this.

Comment: Are you sure that's the case? Hundreds of thousands of Americans travel into Mexico with expensive laptops every year and don't pay anything. Was it because it was a computer tower and not a laptop?

Comment: @JonathanReez It cost me $600 to find out. So, yup, I'm pretty sure. And they tend to ignore laptops because there are so many of them that come through. Once you come through with a large big-ticket item, they will stop you and you will be taxed.